# How can I substitute variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm trying to write unit-test. I have a simple module:

```
var Common = module.exports = {
  unit: {
    somejQueryFn: function() { $('.selector') /* work with jQuery */ }
  }
}
```

Unit-test code:

```
describe('Test jQuery spec', function(){
  var Common = require('common');
  it('not working :( ', function(){
     //Work. I'm using jsdom, for using jQuery in tests; It's a jQuery instance
    expect( typeof $ ).toBe('function');

    //$ is undefined in somejQueryFn; 
    expect( Common.unit.somejQueryFn() ).toBe( result );
  })
})
```

So, how can I handle it? Any ideas?
I have tried using `new Function()`, but i think that is not a good idea.

Comment: `$` has to be defined globally.

Answer (score 1):

How about initializing `Common` with `$`?

```
    module.exports = function ($) {
      return {
        somejQueryFn: function() {
            /* work with $ */ 
        }
      }
    };

    describe('Test jQuery spec', function(){
      var Common = require('common')($);

      it('not working :( ', function(){
        expect( typeof $ ).toBe('function');

        // $ is no longer undefined in somejQueryFn :)
        expect( Common.somejQueryFn() ).toBe( result );
      })
    });
```

Comment: Nice idea! I absolutely forgot about this way. But I should make too much changes in code, to do it in this way(

Answer (score 0):

I'm absolutely stupid. I was thinking, that `var $` will override visibility. I should make `global.$ = window.jQuery` to fix this problem. Thanks to Felix Kling for hint. Felix, if you write an answer, I will mark it like a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a return statement inside of your inner property:

```
var Common = module.exports = {
  unit: {
    somejQueryFn: function() { return $('.selector') /* work with jQuery */ }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are calling somejQueryFn. Currently the function that you listed is not returning anything so it will return undefined.

Comment: That is the not the problem. The problem is that `$` is undefined in the script: `//$ is undefined in somejQueryFn; `.